# Monitoring rs232 traffic

Tags: windows, serial-port, packet-sniffers

I need to monitor RS232 traffic, I'm communicating with a hardware device and i want to monitor that traffic.
Ideally i would want a Wireshark for serial communication?
Any suggestions ?

---

it actually pases through a USB, and gives me virtual COM interface.

MS windows...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used [this](http://www.eltima.com/products/serial-port-monitor/) for a couple of days, but I think it is only a 30 day version, so you would have to purchase it for longer use...

However, the different options seemed quite good to me, especially because you have different views depending how deep you want to dig into the communication.

Comment: i know... i only needed it for some days, so i didn't have to buy it. There are some other options around in the web, but i didn't find anything as good for free.

Comment: Serial COM port monitor at http://sourceforge.net/projects/serial-com-port-monitor/ would appear to cover the requirement with no up-front cost. The Sysinternals PortMon (live.sysinternals.com) will provide the same data with a simpler interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy cheap RS-232 data scopes or you can just use an RS-232 breakout box and hook up another computer's Rx data line in tandem with your serial link so that you can watch the data using a terminal program.

Comment: i cant, it actually pases through a USB, and gives me virtual COM interface

Comment: @Hellfrost: OK - you might want to update your question then, since you're not really looking to monitor RS-232 *per se*, it seems.